# How to pass div id without a form in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to catch the id of the clicked element and pass it to a php page. I am not using a form.

Everything works except no data is being sent to the php page. No errors are showing when i check the code with the browser or in the php log. I just click on the anchor and nothing happens.

I've looked extensively and there is no details on this subject. Every topic talks about passing info through a form

Html code

```
<li class="click" id="name"><a href="#">Name</a></li>
```

JQuery

```
$(".click").click(function() {
        var datastring = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        data: datastring,
        cache: false,
        url: "index.php",
        success: function(ht) {
        alert(ht);
        } 
        });
});
```

index.php

```
if (isset($_POST['datastring'])) {
        $dynamic_list = $_POST['datastring'];
        echo $dynamic_list;
}
```

Comment: datastring  returns any value ?

Comment: i tried to alert the value directly from ajax but nothing shows

Comment: @BillClinton I think #Sidney answer solved your problem go ahead and accept it

Comment: Thank you Basheer, Sydney's answer is correct however it did not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` attribute in that function is supposed to be an object so that it can represent a key => value pair, at the moment you're just giving it a value without a name so it thinks the value is the name and that there is no value.

```
$(".click").click(function() {
        var datastring = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            data: {myparam: datastring},
            cache: false,
            url: "index.php"
        });
});
```

within PHP you should now have index `$_POST['myparam']` which should contain the ID of the element.

I would remove the `var datastring = $(this.attr('id'));` and just use the attribute directly, your example would become this:

```
$(".click").click(function() {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            data: {myparam: $(this).attr('id')},
            cache: false,
            url: "index.php"
        });
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to change the name of the `$_POST` index you can change `myparam` to anything you like so if you want the index in your `$_POST` request to be `datastring` you could change the following line:

`data: { myparam: $(this).attr('id') }`
to
`data: { datastring: $(this).attr('id') }`

which would change your post request from:
`$_POST['myparam']`
to
`$_POST['datastring']`

Since this variable is only used once you might as well not use it at all and just use the direct value anyways :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It's my first time here and so far im glad i joined the community. Unfortunately that did not work and i am still getting no result. Could it be that i have included the index.php file on the same page as the ajax file and im echoing the dynamic list variable?

Comment: The parameter name must be enclosed with quotes. `data: {"myparam": $(this).attr('id')},`

Comment: @ChristianLundahl - oh, in my experience you don't have to do this tho? Could you point me to the docs that say this? I'll update my answer if so ^.^

Answer (score 3):

just replace line

```
data: datastring,
```

with

```
data: {"datastring":datastring},
```